# Not able to add Client folder to local Githb Repo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

I am trying to commit my client folder in my React project to my local Git repo and keep getting this error:

```
% git add client
warning: adding embedded git repository: client
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> client
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached client
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

I ran this to try and remove the current client repo:

```
User@Users-MacBook-Pro final-9 % git rm --cached -f client
rm 'client'
```

and when I try and git add client again I get the same error message at the very top of this post.

Comment: client folder is using as submodule ?

Comment: how do i fix this? I had this problem before and there was a gitignore file there and I deleted it which worked. But this time I don't see a git file.

Comment: is it possible to share sample repository ?

Comment: I fixed this problem. I simply had to commit the changes as opposed to adding again.

Comment: Good. It's solved. You can add answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove .gitignore file in your cient folder
after that type "git add * " in command line again
it will be ok!